# Dynamically add content in Angular with ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, ajax

I have a page on a website based on AngularJS on which content gets loaded via ajax into a div. My problem is that the Angular directives in the loaded content and the controller seem to get ignored. How can I make the controller working?

**HMTL:**

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" id="loadContent">Load Content</a>

<div id="myForm-con">
</div>

<script src="js/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/app.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $('#loadContent').on('click', function() {
    $.post("load-my-form.php", function(data, result) {
      $('#myForm-con').html(data);
    });     
  });
</script>
```

**app.js**

```
(function() {
    var app = angular.module('app', []);

    app.controller('validationCtrl', ['$scope',
        function ($scope) {
            $scope.submitForm = function () {
                $scope.submitted = true;

                if ($scope.myForm.$valid) {
                    alert('form is valid');
                }
            }
        }
    ]);
})();
```

**HTML ajax loaded form**

```
<div ng-controller="validationCtrl">
  <form id="my-form" name="myForm" ng-submit="submitForm()" novalidate>
    ...
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Stop using jQuery AJAX inside an Angular app. Angular has the `$http` module for creating requests.

Answer (score 0):

I'd probably try something like this:

**HTML**

`<a href="#" id="loadContent" ng-click="loadContent()">Load Content</a>`

**Angular**

```
$scope.loadContent() = $http.post("load-my-form.php", data).then(function (result) {
    $('#myForm-con').html(result);
});
```

Or alternatively

**Angular**

```
$scope.formResults = '';
$scope.loadContent() = $http.post("load-my-form.php", data).then(function (result) {
    $scope.formResults = result;
});
```

**HTML**

`<div id="myForm-con">{{formResults}}</div>`

Answer (score 0):

In order for this to work you have to do 2 things:

1 - use angular [http](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) and `.then` for the `callback` -

```
$http.post('/someUrl', data, config).then(successCallback, errorCallback);
```

2- use angular `data-binding` to link your data to a view, for example - [2-ways data-binding](https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_04).